# How to pause outgoing call till verification in android

Tags: android, call, android-broadcastreceiver

I need to pause the outgoing call till I enter correct PIN. Only authorized user can make call . I have used `BroadcastReceiver` for detecting the outgoing call.

This is my code,

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER).toString();

    //if u want to block particular call then check number or else block all call in thid code
    if (worngPIN){
        setResultData(null);//Canceling call operation 
        Toast.makeText(context, "This call is not Allowed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I'm able to  see the `Toast` message but call is connecting.

I tested in version 5.1.

Comment: post error log also